# Multiple app service initialization scaleout on Azure

Tags: azure-app-services

I'm having an issue where on a single app service plan there are multiple sites with the same application. This application has a somewhat heavy initialization.

The issue is that on scale out, the initialization is run for all sites at once, and sites are brought onto the new instance is *their* initialization completes. This means that some sites may be directed to the new instance while initialization of other sites is not complete, sending the user to a server under high load.

Does anyone have a good solution for this? Right now I'm thinking I may have to use a separate plan for each site.